# Ubuntu 22.04 Gnome Files Networks how to sftp connect to machine listening on port other than 22

Tags: sftp

Just upgraded my laptop to 22.04, very nice.

However I can't work out how to connect to a remote linux from the Files app; the remote machine is not listening on port 22.

I can connect from the command line using `sftp -P not_port_22 user@host`

On 18.04, in files, I could configure the port number before connecting; I can't find any such option on 22.04

[image: Screen shot of "files" app]

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you so much. Yes, convert to answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It looks a bit different now

Click **Other Locations**, the last item on the left panel.

At the bottom of the right panel where it says **Connect to Server**, type:

```
sftp://user@host:not_port_22
```

Here is a picture:

[image]

Then click the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button.

Once connected you will see a new item on the left panel. Right click on that item and "Bookmark" it for future use. Once bookmarked, you may want to "Rename" it something more humanly understandable.

Hope this helps